# Can not run java in spark worker

Tags: java, apache-spark

When I was running a spark program in the cluster, I got this error in log:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/cloud/packages/spark-0.9.0-incubating-bin-hadoop1/work/app-20140424114752-0000/0"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.ExecutorRunner.fetchAndRunExecutor(ExecutorRunner.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.ExecutorRunner$$anon$1.run(ExecutorRunner.scala:59)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:148)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 2 more
```

I have set JAVA_HOME(`/cloud/packages/jdk1.6.0_38`) and SPARK_HOME(`/cloud/packages/spark-0.9.0-incubating-bin-hadoop1`).

What's the causes of this exception? How to fixed it?

Comment: Can you pls check java version. java -version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same issue on Ubuntu 12.04, and fixed it by adding `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/environment`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I lost the opportunity to solve this problem. Because the machine was reinstall for some fatal crash.

Answer (score 0):

Check your java version.

```
java -version
```

If java is installed properly it displays Java version.

If not Install java(Ubundu)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

**update**

Please check `echo $JAVA_HOME`.

Else set java home in `.bashrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/cloud/packages/jdk1.6.0_38 
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: the `java -version` result:
    java version "1.6.0_38"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: java is on my server.

Comment: Most of my work is implemented by Java. All of these have done before. But why spark throw an exception that cannot run `java`?

Comment: Sezina: are you able to print echo $JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Yes. The result is the right one that I use on the server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51328/discussion-between-sreeveni-and-sezina)

Answer (score 0):

In a shell, you are accustomed to being able to run `java` and letting the shell consult the `PATH` to go find where it is. Here you are invoking a command directly in the OS. It can't find `java` as it says. You can use a shell like `bash` to invoke the command for you, or give a full path to `java`.

Why though? why not run Java code inside the worker?